# Facebook Connect and iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, facebook

Is there a mechanism to use Facebook Connect to authenticate via a custom developed iPhone application? Would that require embedding WebKit as a browser and using the authentication there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the official library for it.

<strike>http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_for_iPhone</strike>

**edit** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios